# Classic asp how to read xml data

Tags: xml

I'm trying to use ip api to display country's name where user is trying to access. I can parse xml fine but i can't select just country's name tag and display it. Any help would be truly appreciated.

```
<%

Dim URL, objXML, value
URL = "http://ip-api.com/xml/ipaddress"
Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
objXML.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
objXML.async =  False
objXML.Load URL

Response.Write objXML.parseError.reason

value = objXML.documentElement.Text

set objXML = nothing

%>

<%= value %>
```

this code turns xml into text. Instead i would like to use only country tag and response.write that info.

xml data should read something like this

```
    <query>
<status>
data here
</status>
<country>
data here
</country>
<countryCode>
data here
</countryCode>
<region>
data here
</region>
<regionName>
data here
</regionName>
<city>
data here
</city>
<zip>
data here
</zip>
<lat>
data here
</lat>
<lon>
data here
</lon>
<timezone>
data here
</timezone>
<isp>
data here
</isp>
<org>
data here
</org>
<as>
data here
</as>
<query>
data here
</query>
</query>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%
value = objXML.selectSingleNode("//query/country").text
Response.Write value
%>
```